# How to create an event of the Custom control to support converting to the Command?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, command, custom-controls

I created Custom control has an event as below.

```
public class Editor : Control
{
    ...
    public event EventHandler<AlarmCollection> AlarmFired = null;
    ...
}
```

And the above event is called (if not null) when TextChanged event is fired.

```
private async void TextArea_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    this.AlarmFired?.Invoke(this, this.alarmList);
    ...
}
```

Now I try to bind the above event to the ViewModel externally as below.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type documentViewModels:EditorTypeViewModel}">
    <editor:Editor FontSize="15" FontFamily="Arial"
                                 KeywordForeground="LightBlue">

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="AlarmFired">
                <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AlarmFiredCommand}"
                                     PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                     EventArgsConverter="{localConverters:RemoveObjectConverter}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </editor:Editor>

</DataTemplate>
```

The define of EditorTypeViewModel is as shown below.

```
public class EditorTypeViewModel : DocumentViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler<AlarmCollection> AlarmFired = null;

    public EditorTypeViewModel(string title) : base(title)
    {
    }

    private RelayCommand<AlarmCollection> alarmFiredCommand = null;
    public RelayCommand<AlarmCollection> AlarmFiredCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.alarmFiredCommand == null)
                this.alarmFiredCommand = new RelayCommand<AlarmCollection>(this.OnAlarmFired);

            return this.alarmFiredCommand;
        }
    }

    private void OnAlarmFired(AlarmCollection alarmInfos)
    {


        this.AlarmFired?.Invoke(this, alarmInfos);
    }
}
```

When I executed the above program, OnAlarmFired method connected with RelayCommand is not called.
I tried to find the cause and found a suspicious point.

A suspicious point is the value of the AlarmFired event of the Editor is null when the TextChanged method of the Editor is called. It shows at below.

[image]

***I thought AlarmFired wasn't null because it would be connected with Command but it wasn't.***

What I try to do is that binding the event of the CustomControl to the Command of the ViewModel and use it.

For example, the MouseDoubleClick event of the ListView can be bind to the MouseDoubleClickCommand as below. 
The MouseDoubleClickCommand would gain a right of control when MouseDoubleClick event is fired.

```
<ListView>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}"
                                 PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</ListView>
```

***I would like to create an event to support converting to the Command like MouseDoubleClick of ListView*** 
(I don't want to create Command in the CustomControl because the number of events is a lot)

What I should do to achieve this goal?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass your event argument to your `ViewModel`, you should create a new `Behavior` like this:

```
public class EventToCommandBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    private Delegate _handler;
    private EventInfo _oldEvent;

    // Event
    public string Event
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(EventProperty);
        set => SetValue(EventProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EventProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Event", typeof(string), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnEventChanged));

    // Command
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    // PassArguments (default: false)
    public bool PassArguments
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(PassArgumentsProperty);
        set => SetValue(PassArgumentsProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PassArgumentsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PassArguments", typeof(bool), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));


    private static void OnEventChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var beh = (EventToCommandBehavior)d;

        if (beh.AssociatedObject != null) // is not yet attached at initial load
            beh.AttachHandler((string)e.NewValue);
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AttachHandler(Event); // initial set
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attaches the handler to the event
    /// </summary>
    private void AttachHandler(string eventName)
    {
        // detach old event
        if (_oldEvent != null)
            _oldEvent.RemoveEventHandler(AssociatedObject, _handler);

        // attach new event
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventName))
        {
            var ei = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);
            if (ei != null)
            {
                var mi = GetType().GetMethod("ExecuteCommand", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                if (mi != null) _handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, this, mi);
                ei.AddEventHandler(AssociatedObject, _handler);
                _oldEvent = ei; // store to detach in case the Event property changes
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException($"The event '{eventName}' was not found on type '{AssociatedObject.GetType().Name}'");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the Command
    /// </summary>
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedParameter.Local
    private void ExecuteCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object parameter = PassArguments ? e : null;
        if (Command == null) return;
        if (Command.CanExecute(parameter))
            Command.Execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
<ListView>
      <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding AlarmFiredCommand}" Event="AlarmFired" PassArguments="True" />
      </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

Note: If you want to pass your arguments should set True for `PassArguments`  property

Comment: This is a good idea but what I really want is to use CustomControl like basic control of the Visual Studio without to create other modules. (ex : ListView example)
Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Comment: It isn't easily supported. there is an article here: https://weblogs.asp.net/alexeyzakharov/silverlight-commands-hacks-passing-eventargs-as-commandparameter-to-delegatecommand-triggered-by-eventtrigger

Comment: Oh, thank you for the information. If there is no better answer by tomorrow morning then I would adopt this article.